# How to resolve File to Patch issue?

Tags: 8, version-control

We are trying to apply a patch to a core module using [Applying patches](https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply) after updating [Drupal core to 8.5.6](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.5.6). When running `patch -p1 < patchname-issuenum-version.patch` command, we get the following.

We tried entering `/core/modules/some/path/file.php` but that did not work. I ran the command from the `/core/modules/some/` directory, which is the module's root folder.

How do we resolve the `File to Patch` issue?

```
$ patch -p1 < patchname-issuenum-version.patch
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/core/modules/some/path/file.php b/core/modules/some/path/file.php
|index cb2e5754a..12354789 11111
|--- a/core/modules/some/path/file.php
|+++ b/core/modules/some/path/file.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `patch -p1 < patchname-issuenum-version.patch` from the directory containing the *core* directory, not from core/mdoules/some/ or core/modules/some/. (I take *core/mdoules/some/* is a typo in the question body.)

Patches for Drupal core are created from the Drupal root directory, so when you apply a Drupal patch, you need to change directory to that one.